# Почему этот код не проходит проверку на leetcode, несмотря на то что работает в браузере

Tags: javascript

Задача такова: даны два массива с числами, нужно развернуть каждый массив, в каждом из массивов соединить все числа в одно, например: [5, 3, 1] становится 135, во втором массиве [2,4,8] становится
842.

Затем получить сумму этих двух получившихся чисел.

И наконец, вернуть массив состоящий из цифр той суммы.
[**Ссылка на задачу**](https://leetcode.com/problems/add-two-numbers/)

вот мой код, который правильно выводит каждый пример на сайте. На при запуске кода редактор на сайте показывает очень странную ошибку "l1.reverse is not a function" хотя l1 это массив

```
    var addTwoNumbers = function(l1, l2) {
        // проверка что массив l1 содержит цифры от 0 до 9
        for (let i = 0; i < l1.length; i++) {
            if(l1[i] < 0 || l1 > 9) return  
        }
            // проверка что массив l2 содержит цифры от 0 до 9
            for (let i = 0; i < l2.length; i++) {
                if(l2[i] < 0 || l2 > 9) return  
            }
            
            // получаю  сумму всех чисел в обоих массивах, предворительно
            // развернув массив, сделав из него строку а затем превратив строку в число
            let arrSum = +l1.reverse().join('') + +l2.reverse().join('')
            
            // превращаю сумму в строку, а затем эту строку в массив, и делаю реверс масива
            let reverseArrSum = (arrSum + '').split('').reverse();
            let res = []
            // числа в массиве являются строками, поэтому делаем из них числа
            // и закидываем в новый массив res
            for(let i = 0; i < reverseArrSum.length; i++) {
                if(reverseArrSum[i])
                res.push(+reverseArrSum[i])
            }
            return res
        };
```

Comment: Может надо проверить что на вход дали массивы?) может строку дали)

Comment: в данном случае `l1.reverse().join('') + +l2.reverse().join('')`ты складываешь строку с числом, а не числа, поэтому для случая `1+1` получаешь `11` а не `2`

Comment: стоит добавить ссылку на саму задачу.

Comment: Я извиняюсь, видимо при редактировании плюсик случайно удалил. На самом деле там  +l1.reverse().join('') + +l2.reverse().join('')

Comment: ссылку на задачу все равно стоит добавить, возможно действительно в формулировке не указано, что на вход подаются именно массивы

Comment: вот ссылка на саму задачу. Попробуйте вставить мой код и нажать run code, и навести на красный восклицательный знак с ошибкой    https://leetcode.com/problems/add-two-numbers/

Comment: _You are given two non-empty linked lists_ - собственно в задаче явно указано, что на вход подается связанный список, а не массив. И перед кодом описание узла этого списка

Comment: но я решаю задачу в языке javascript, разве в js есть связанные списки? Я подумал, что в js два связанных списка имеется в виду что есть два массива

Comment: @Александр, связный список - это структура данных, в которой есть узлы, хранящие данные, и из каждого узла есть способ перейти к следующему. Для ее реализации не нужно никакой встроенной структуры. Достаточно, как и указано в комментарии к коду, одного класса с полем val и полем `next`

Comment: В общем я не правильно понял вопрос. Я думал что нужно работать с массивами, а оказалось что что со связанными списками. Хороший урок на будущее, нужно внимательнее читать текст задачи и понимать что с тебя требуется

Answer (score 0):

В тексте задачи явно указывается

> You are given two non-empty **linked lists**

Что означает, на вход подаются **связные списки**, а не массивы.

Далее в комментариях перед кодом указано определение для элементов списка

```
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * function ListNode(val, next) {
 *     this.val = (val===undefined ? 0 : val)
 *     this.next = (next===undefined ? null : next)
 * }
 */
```

А также явно указаны типы параметров

```
/**
 * @param {ListNode} l1
 * @param {ListNode} l2
 * @return {ListNode}
 */
var addTwoNumbers = function(l1, l2) {
```

Так как значения параметров не массивы, при попытке вызвать у них метод массива и вызывает указанную ошибку.

---

Как было справедливо указано, подход с переводом списка в число и обратно, может не сработать из-за большого размера. Вместо этого необходимо было реализовать поразрядное сложение, с переносом лишнего в старший разряд.

Алгоритм довольно простой:

1. взять текущие элементы списков
2. сложить их и добавить перебор с прошлой итерации
3. сохранить последнюю цифру результата
4. если сумма больше 10 - установить в перебор 1 иначе 0
5. повторять 1-4 пока есть элементы в списках, либо перебор не равен 0

Answer (score -1):

Потому что в массивах может быть 100 элементов. Double не поддерживает такую точность. Пробуй BigInt, если он там работает.

Comment: в задаче нет речь про массив

Comment: @Grundy, а это что? https://i.stack.imgur.com/Asatp.png

Comment: Это прямое указание, что количество элементов, в связном списке не больше 100, где ты массив-то нашел? :) _in range [1,100]_ - означает, что может быть от одного до 100 элементов

Comment: Тем более, там же явно указано, что именно в функцию подается: https://imgur.com/ajLMbmU

Comment: @Grundy, и как это влияет на то, что 100 цифр в double не лезет?

Comment: нет массивов, нет смысла в одно больше число конвертировать

Comment: @Grundy, у автора вопроса массивы есть. А уж откуда он их взял - его дело. И уж тем более наличие или отсутствие массивов никак не влияет на возможность конвертирования в число.

Comment: не :) вопрос автора как раз в том, что не проходит тест, а тест не проходит именно потому, что входные данные не массивы, на которые рассчитывал автор ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Grundy, ну пиши ответ тогда.